# Handling async funtion of Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm using firebase as my database for my mobile app that i create with react native. I once use it in a web app, and i remember that there is some part of firebase that is async function. Now when i want to use firebase in react, i meet the same problem, and i forgot how to solve it.

```
function viewName(userId) {
  firebase.database().ref('player/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const userName = snapshot.val.name;
    return userName;
  });
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
  <Text>{viewName('0')}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

It's only a mock app, not the real app. I'm trying to receive the name of user with key "0" (player/0/name), then show it as  on the app screen. But as u can guess,the viewName() function return nothing...

Can someone help me?
(Sorry if it's sounds stupid or if my question make no sense. First time asking here, and first time using react)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function viewName(userId, cb) {
  firebase.database().ref('player/' + userId).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const userName = snapshot.val.name;
    cb(userName);
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('')
  React.useEffect(() => {
    viewName('0', setUsername)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Text>{username}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `firebase.database().ref().on()` is a callback style async function, so `return` does nothing. You need a structure to get that return value. Simple way is to use another callback (`cb` in my answer).

Comment: basically when that async function complete, the `cb` passed in is called with the return value you need. And I pass in `setUsername`, so `setUsername(userName)` is called when completed, thus change value of `username` in component and trigger a re-render.